# How did Shelob stab Frodo through his mithril shirt?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

How come Shelob's sting was able to pierce through the Mithril armor worn by Frodo and poison him?

Answer (score 7):

Shelob stung Frodo in his neck, which was not covered by the mithril shirt that he wore.

> As he had run forward, eager, rejoicing to be free, Shelob with hideous speed had come 
>   behind and with one swift stroke had stung him in the neck. He lay now pale, and heard no voice, and did not move.
>
> <sub>The Two Towers: The Choices of Master Samwise</sub>

Comment: this explanation does not apply to the movie canon, in which she stabs him in the abdomen

Comment: Movie plot-hole then, canon is the books